# How to validate floating number in [input type=text]

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need a regular expression which validate the floating point number, I have build the following.

```html
<label for="salary">Enter floating nunmber:</label>
<input type="text" id="salary" name="salary" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^-0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1').replace(/(\-.*)\-/g, '$1');" />
```

It works but it fails in case of `11-111`. How to I fix it.

Comment: why don't use type number ?

Comment: /^-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/ should match en style numbers, set in the inputs pattern attribute

Comment: @MikeT input type number allows "------122"

Comment: i think you @'ed the wrong person, i suggested the pattern attribute for validation not to use the input type number. the pattern attribute is used to validate the entire control not the typed input see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
const validateFloat = (e) => {
    let val = e.currentTarget.value;
    if(isNaN(val)){
        val = val.replace(/[^-0-9\.]/g,'');
        if(val.split('.').length>2) 
             val =val.replace(/\.+$/,"");
    }
    e.currentTarget.value = val; 
}
```

Using:

```
input.addEventListener("input", validateFloat);
```

Working with negative values too.

Comment: The pattern 11-111 fail like OP example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1')` like:

```html
<label for="salary">Enter floating nunmber:</label>
<input type="text" id="salary" name="salary" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1')" />
```

Comment: -33 is not working

Comment: Why should a salary be negative? :D And edit your question because you ask only for 11-111 pattern

Comment: What salary? :D

Comment: `for="salary" id="salary" name="salary"` Seems like is for user salary :)

Answer (score 0):

The sort of input validation you are trying here is going to be monstrous in a single regEx so you would be better off breaking it into several smaller ones

- `/[^0-9-.]/g` to remove any none valid characters
- `/(-.*)-/g` to remove any extra -
- `/(\..*)\./g` to remove any extra .

this would look like this

```
let val = '-abc123.45.67-89';

val = val.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '');
val = val.replace(/(-.*?)-/g, '$1');
val = val.replace(/(\..*?)\./g, '$1');

console.log(val)
//"-123.456789"
```

if you are performing this on every char input then this should work fine however on bulk entry (ie a paste) you may need to loop the replaces to take into account that previous matches wont be included in the next match

eg

```
let val = '-123-abc.123.45.67-89';

val = val.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '');
const minusMatch = /(-.*?)-/g;
while(val.search(minusMatch)>=0){
    val = val.replace(minusMatch, '$1');
}
const dotMatch = /(\..*?)\./g;
while(val.search(dotMatch)>=0){
    val = val.replace(dotMatch, '$1');
}
console.log(val)
```

Comment: What about `-123-abc123.45.67-89`

Comment: when this runs it sees -123- as the first match, and removes the - from the end it then starts looking again from abc and as -89 is the first - it then starts looking for a - after it for a duplicate, so the each run will always remove the 2nd, 4th and 6th - , if you are typing in the text 1 number at a time this will remove all extra - as they will always be the 2nd, but bulk entry requires multiple runs to get them all

Comment: added an example of the looped variant

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution

```html
<label for="floatingNunmber">Enter floating nunmber:</label>
<input type="text" id="floatingNunmber" name="floatingNunmber" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1').replace(/(\-.*)\-/g, '$1');" />
```